# How do I know if a site linking to me is spam that needs to be disavowed?

Tags: backlinks, spam, disavow-links

Today i see my google webmaster dashboard links and **Top linking sites**.

A site with an address : `example.com` linked my 50 pages.

I tried to use a spam checker website to see if this domain is problematic, but I don't know how to identify spammy sites like that.

I want to identify if this site is spam or not so that I can know if I need disavow this website!

Answer (score 3):

In general, Google is good at filtering out spammy links when ranking your site. According to Google, disavowal is only useful in specific circumstances.

> You should disavow backlinks only if:
>
> 1. You have a considerable number of spammy, artificial, or low-quality links pointing to your site,
>
> **AND**
>
> 2. The links have caused a manual action, or likely will cause a manual action, on your site.
>
> https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en

I doubt that links from one single spammy site would net you a manual action in Google Search Console, but if you are worried, I would consider manually checking the site by hand.

- Does the website look "real" or does it look machine generated?
- Does it link using a natural pattern, or does it shove links into article text willy-nilly, regardless of the link's relevance?
- Where is it linking to your site? Do the links to your site make any sense at all?

People might say that it's risky to visit an untrusted website like this, but I don't think it's a big deal as long as your browser is up-to-date and you close the window if any funny business happens (redirects to other domains, alert boxes, etc.)

If the site looks terribly spammy, and you are sure that the links pointing from it are absolutely worthless, then it couldn't hurt to disavow. But disavowal is commonly overused, and if there's any link equity at all, disavowal could hurt your site unnecessarily.

It's probably best to just let it be, unless you suspect that a competitor is specifically targeting you with a negative seo attack (which is very rare, I've never heard of such an attack in practice).